# Where is the set_c0_status() function defined?

Tags: gcc, mips

The code at:

https://github.com/intel/linux-intel-4.9/blob/master/arch/mips/cavium-octeon/octeon-irq.c

Uses the function or macro **set_c0_status()**

Where is that defined?
If this is built into the GCC MIPS compiler, then where is it documented ?

Comment: Really puzzling! I'm no kernel expert, but it is the first time I can't find the declaration of a function!

Comment: Me too!  It is because I this is defined by a weird universal macro.  I usually use the Perl RegEx to find function definitions:  [\s\*]+FindmeFn\s*+(\((?:[^\(\)]++|(?1))*\))\s*?{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set_c0_status` function is defined in `mipsregs.h` and expanded by the following macro hierarchy:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/mips/include/asm/mipsregs.h

```
/*
 * Manipulate bits in a register.
 */
#define __BUILD_SET_COMMON(name)                                \
static inline unsigned int                                      \

set_##name(unsigned int set)                                    \
{                                                               \
        unsigned int res, new;                                  \
                                                                \
        res = read_##name();                                    \
        new = res | set;                                        \
        write_##name(new);                                      \
                                                                \
        return res;                                             \
}                                                               \

...

/*
 * Manipulate bits in a c0 register.
 */
#define __BUILD_SET_C0(name)    __BUILD_SET_COMMON(c0_##name)

__BUILD_SET_C0(status)
```

Comment: Thanks.  What a weird macro!

Answer (score 1):

I found this in arch/mips/kvm/kvm_mips.c

```
static
void kvm_mips_set_c0_status (void)
{
    uint32_t status = read_c0_status();

    if (cpu_has_fpu)
    status |= (ST0_CU1);

    if (cpu_has_dsp)
    status |= (ST0_MX);

    write_c0_status(status);
    __asm volatile ("ehb");
}
```

and the write_c0_status is defined in mipsregs.h ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/mips/include/asm/mipsregs.h#L1639 ), So I guess you should look there for the answer.